# Change select that is dynamically generated

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have two selects. Category and Subcategory.

I've tried to changed them like this:

```
var select_cat = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select")["cat"];
select_cat.Focus();
select_cat.SetAttribute("value", "2");
select_cat.InvokeMember("onchange");
select_cat.RemoveFocus();

var select_subcat = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select")["subcat"];
select_subcat.Focus();
select_subcat.SetAttribute("value", "102");
select_subcat.InvokeMember("onchange");
select_subcat.RemoveFocus();
```

The subcat select is generated dynamically, based on what is selected in the first one(category).
If I run this code, I get exception: **A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred**
This is because the subcat select doesn't exists for the webBrowser1 element I guess. Is there any way to select them one after another?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry about inculding tags in my title. Will never do it again.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `select_cat.InvokeMember("onchange")` is starting a new "thread" in the browser.  You are therefore calling `select_subcat` before subcat is populated by the onchange event.  You will have to either call the function called by "onchange" directly in your code, or implement some sort of spinlock to wait for subcat to populate.

Comment: I was thinking to wait for it to populate somehow but nothing came to my mind.

Comment: Do you have access to the Javascript Code?  You could set the attribute in the onchange event for select_cat rather than in c#.